# For Ruby on Rails, how to "gem install mysql2" after upgrading from Leopard to Snow Leopard?

Tags: sqlite, mysql2, ruby-on-rails-3

It always says:

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/peter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

---

similar things happen if it is sqlite3:

```
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/peter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

---

**Update: at least sqlite3 is building now**... that is after I `rvm remove 1.9.2-p180` and removing all the 1.9.2, and reinstall by `rvm install 1.9.2` and now sqlite3 can be bundle installed, but mysql2 still has problem.

Comment: sigh... somehow I feel like I am building things as if I am doing programming with a couple of friends who are experimenting with things and always breaking things in high school, or in a computer class where the Professor is busy publishing papers, and the TA is busy with their classes and smoking, and the lab project is a mess

Comment: Please show content of mkmf.log saved in gem's directory.

Comment: i installed the 64-bit version of MySQL and now I can bundle install, but when I `rails g scaffold foo name:string`, then it will say:  `/Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails305/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in 'require': dlopen(/Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails305/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)`

Comment: seems like the above can be fixed by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve   but there is talk about using sudo or no sudo... i use rvm but used sudo already with that line... hope that didn't affect anything... i didn't even know what `install_name_tool` is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the 64 bit version of MySQL server and it will bundle install, and then this question helped with the

```
Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
```

solution: [Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib error when trying to run 'rails server' on OS X 10.6 with mysql2 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve)