# rails server command failing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard, rubygems

I'm on OS X Snow Leopard, I have installed MySQL using the OS X packages found on the MySQL download website, Ruby 1.8.7 from source code (`which ruby` yields `usr/local/bin/ruby` only) and RubyGem 1.7.1 (upgraded from 1.3.1 using `gem update --system`) from source code too (after updating `gem` I re-ran `gem update`). The start/stop MySQL server prefpane is installed, too.

After this I have installed the `rdoc`, `mysql` and `mysql2` gems using `gem install rdoc`, `gem install mysql` and `gem install mysql2`, in this order.

After creating a sample project, I modified the `database.yml` so that mysql is the db used instead of sqlite3.

Then, I `cd` into the project folder and run `rails server` with the following error:

> sample$ rails server
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle:
>   dlopen(/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle,
>   9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
>   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>   Reason: image not found -
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8
>     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in
>   `require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in
>   `each'    from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
>   `each'    from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler.rb:120:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/riccardo/Workspace/restaurant/config/application.rb:7  from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
>     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in
>   `tap'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
>     from script/rails:6:in`require'    from script/rails:6

What's wrong with my configuration?
I read that there are  files to rename (?) but I did not understand how.
Thanks very much in advance to everybody
Riccardo

Comment: http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-fix-mysql-load-issues-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar (if not identical) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve) problem. There are a number of possible solutions on that question.