# Problem Starting Ruby on Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I am completely new to Ruby, Rails, and MySQL. I am trying to start a new project and start the default server and I get the error listed below. I have the following installed:

- Ruby : ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i686-darwin9.8.0]
- Rails: rails (3.0.7)
- MySql: mysql2 (0.2.7)
- RubyGems: 1.7.2

Error is below:

```
$ rails s
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlsym(0x251680, Init_mysql2): symbol not found - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/nelsonwittwer/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

I'm not quite sure where to go from here and would love any help you may have. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have mysql2 gem installed in your ruby system. To check it use **gem list -d**. If mysql2 gem not found, in ubuntu you must install following library before install mysql2 gem :

```
# sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev  (for mysql-5.*)

# sudo apt-get install  libmysql-ruby  ruby-dev
```

After that, you could install with **sudo gem install mysql2** and make sure your adapter value inside database.yml is mysql2. Another issue is Library not loaded, you can view this link if that the problem [Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib error when trying to run 'rails server' on OS X 10.6 with mysql2 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve)

Answer (score 0):

You need the mySQL gem installed on your system.

Now, DO NOT use apt-get to install this, as apt-get often has old versions of the ruby libraries.

Also, I would highly recommend you use SQLite when starting out.
And, Bundler is also very helpful (described in the [railstutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/))

On ubuntu/debian based distributions (and you really want to use MySQL):

If you are using ruby 1.8.x (check with `ruby -v`):

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo gem install mysql2
```

If you are using ruby 1.9.x:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
sudo gem install mysql2
```