# rails server error ? (rails 3)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/imran/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this?? Thanks in advance ;-)

now i'm getting this?

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
>   _mysql_get_client_info   Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>   Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap

Comment: do you have `mysql2` gem installed?

Comment: Are you sure you installed MySQL (both the Gem and MySQL itself)?

Comment: mysql is running and i got mysql (2.8.1) mysql2 (0.3.2) gems installed?

Comment: yep! macbook pro snow leopard

Comment: Yes, he's on a Mac. Everything is installed in /Library.

Comment: Why do you use mysql (2.8.1) ? I think you can't use both for one application, do you have this 2 gems in your GemFile ?

Comment: I'm using a MAC with rvm, MAMP (mysql5), rails 3 and gem mysql2 (after switch from mysql), and ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @Dinatih  why did you switch from mysql to MAMP (mysql5)? Did you have problems with mysql?

Comment: I switched because I also switch from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 (1.9.2 and the gem mysql are some trouble with caractere encoding). I use MAMP because I just prefere it, and as it's a little difficult to use both MAMP and rails (you must get mysql's header files separately and put it in MAMP folder), I thought you had the same problem

Comment: Do you use the system' MySQL version of MAC OS X or do you have reinstalled it (for example with macport or manually) ?

Answer (score 1):

may be this post is similiar with your problem :
[Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib error when trying to run 'rails server' on OS X 10.6 with mysql2 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve)

Comment: Thanks! this page explained whats happening but i still could'nt fix the problem http://lightyearsoftware.com/2011/02/mysql-5-5-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/"
```

Put this in your .profile (or .bashrc) and type this command

my_term> source .profile

replace '/usr/local/mysql/lib/' by where you MySQL client is installed

Comment: thanks i tried this but didnt work! i now get the second error i just pasted above!

Comment: pasted it above after now i'm getting this

Comment: @Imran were you able to solve this? I am stuck at the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Updated MySQL again from installer (say, `mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64`).

Then MySQL2 gem:
`$ sudo gem install mysql2 -- 
--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For permanent fix, try to create a soft link by command -

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
```

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/07/getting-error-library-not-loaded.html

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and any suggestions I found here or in other questions didn't get me anywhere, but running as root did (with `sudo rails s`). I guess that when running as root, it uses the right path to the mysql library, but changing it with `install_name_tool` as described in one of the links here doesn't work, too. As long as I don't find the issue, I need to start my rails app with sudo.