# Ruby on Rails and MySQL error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails, and have been getting the following error every time I run:

```
rails s
```

I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap
```

I've done quite a bit of research on this on StackOverflow and good ol' Google, and have tried the solutions on this post: [rails server error ? (rails 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833885/rails-server-error-rails-3)  with editing the .profile file, as well as ensuring that mysql and ruby are were both installed for 64-bit systems.

I'm running on OSX Snow Leopard, using Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run Rails 3 you need ruby 1.9.2. I would start there before going any further, please check this link out, your best bet is to use rvm to manage your ruby version. Regards

http://amerine.net/2010/02/24/rvm-rails3-ruby-1-9-2-setup.html