# Unable to Run Rails Server on Port 80 in Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-yosemite, rubymine-7

I am using RubyMine. I recently upgraded from Snow Leopard to Yosemite. When I try to set Port 80 I get following error.

```
/Users/xx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:206:in `bind': Permission denied - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:80 (Errno::EACCES)
```

I did not have such issue on 10.6.8. Is it possible to run on port 80?

Comment: Did you make sure you don't have anything else running on port 80?

Comment: Port numbers < 1024 are protected and require `sudo`, IIRC.

Comment: @sebkomianos No it is not opened

Comment: @sevenseacat I did not have such issue for 10.6.8 at all. Now I don' know how to make RubyMine run a command with Sudo

Comment: What happens if you do `rails s -p 80` in your terminal?

Comment: @sebkomianos `.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 15 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)`

Comment: @Volatil3 This looks like a different problem, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212116/rails-could-not-find-railties

Comment: It is giving same bind issue from command line

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
vmsudo rails server -p 80
```

Answer (score 0):

As @sevenseacat said you have to run with `sudo` for ports below 1024. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351844/how-to-run-rails-s-p80-on-80-port) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840633/start-webrick-in-port-80-mysql2-gem-issue).

While we are at it, though, may I recommend [pow](http://pow.cx/)?

Comment: rvmsudo is not working either saying:

`Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:`. I did this ` export rvmsudo_secure_path=1`, still no difference