# Rails server won't run with mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I know this is a popular issue here, but I just can't seem to get it to run. I've tried just about everything I've read, and the issue persist.

I'm using RVM and 1.9.2. I'm also using MySQL 5.5, and I've reinstalled it several times. My installation of Ruby seems to work well with SQLite, but it chokes on MySQL. I've checked to see if MySQL is working through PHP too, so I know that's not the issue. Rails just can't seem to find the "libmysqlclient.18.dylib" file.

Here's what happens when I run the server:**

```
littleMac$ sudo rails s
/Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/littleMac in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/littleMac in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require': dlopen(/Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/littleMac/sites/TestBox2/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/littleMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RVM chances are you don't want to `sudo`.

Please also format your code in a code block to make it easier for people to help.

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve). It seems to be identical.

Comment: I tried without "sudo", and the result was the same. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Sorry about the messy question, I'll get it reformatted. I'm new to StackOverFlow.

Comment: I read through the link you sent, and this command   `sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle` worked

Comment: Then can you mark my question as correct so other people having your issues know.