# Problem with rake - unable to load mysql2 library

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

A few things. I have mysql and the mysql2 gems installed. I have also edited the gem file to require the mysql2 gem. I have also tried this with both 0.3.6 and 0.2.7 versions of the gem. Both get me the same error when running:

```
rake db:migrate
```

The error is:

```
dlopen(/Users/rdear/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/
mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Referenced from: /Users/rdear/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-
0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Reason: image not found - /Users/rdear/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-
0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Also the database.yml is set to use the mysql2 adapter.

I have spent two days now trying to get mysql working with Rails. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like this is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve.

Comment: I tried that. It's still not working. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (add to ~/.bash_profile if you're using a Bash shell, not .profile):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then do:

`source ~/.bash_profile`