# After upgrading Ruby1.9.2 from p180 to p290, libruby dynamic library path isn't updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, upgrade, dylib

I used RVM to upgrade Ruby 1.9.2 from patch level p180 to p290:

```
rvm upgrade 1.9.2-p180 1.9.2-p290
```

Then, I used these commands to update my Rails gem and other gems

```
gem install rails 3.0.5
gem update
```

Everything seems to be fine; `rvm info` shows all Ruby binaries and gems have been moved to the correct p290 path (~/.rvm/*/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*).

However, when I go to my Rails application directory and issue the command `rails console`, I get the error message saying a gem (activesupport-3.0.5) cannot load the `libruby.1.9.1.dylib` file.

> 10:30 AM ~/Development/rails_projects/my_app_0515 $ rails console
>
> /Users/whk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': dlopen(/Users/whk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/serialport-1.0.4/lib/serialport.bundle, 9): **Library not loaded: /Users/whk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib (LoadError)**
>   Referenced from: /Users/whk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/serialport-1.0.4/lib/serialport.bundle
>   Reason: image not found - /Users/whk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/serialport-1.0.4/lib/serialport.bundle
>   . . .

Rails can't find the dylib file in `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib`, because the `p180` path no longer exists, but the file is in `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib`.

From a separate [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve), I found a workaround is adding this line to .bashrc

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/whk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

However, I want to understand why the rvm ruby upgrade doesn't take care of the lib path change? Does anyone know a cleaner solution -- one that removes the p180 path from where it is configured?

Here are my environment:

- Mac OS X 10.6.6 (Snow Leopard)
- rvm 1.8.4
- ruby 1.9.2p290
- Rails 3.0.5

Thanks!

Comment: I have had a generally negative experience with p290. Many gems won't install etc. I actually am specifying `rvm 1.9.2-p180@some_gemset` for now.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in gems native extension - their were nto rebuild during `rvm upgrade 1.9.2-p180 1.9.2-p290` - next time please have closer look on the output ... it should give your information what's wrong.

as for this particular use case it shoudl be enough to reinstall the given gem:

```
gem install serialport -v 1.0.4
```

... not sure if it should be uninstalled first

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I had tried it, and unfortunately it didn't work. I uncommented the workaround I had in .bashrc, uninstalled and re-installed the serialport gem successfully, and tried rails conole again. I saw the same error.

Comment: it still feels like the same issue, have you tried on empty ruby, with new name? `rvm install 1.9.3-named` and use it `rvm use 1.9.3-named`

Comment: No, I haven't tried. I don't want to tamper with the current working setup where I'm doing active development. In the future, I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: installing named ruby and testing your problem with it will not mess your other rubies, it's completely safe