# trouble installing rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

So I am trying to install RVM, but I think there is a conflict with Xcode on my mac computer. I used to run `rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320`
and  this was my error
The provided compiler

```
'/usr/bin/gcc' is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

I then read a solution to write `rvm get head` and its successful, but when I run rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320 again, I get this error.

```
No binary rubies available for: ///ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
The provided compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
'rvm_codesign_identity' is not set, please set it in ~/.rvmrc
```

Comment: http://caiustheory.com/install-gcc-421-apple-build-56663-with-xcode-42

Comment: @ConnorPhillips can you upgrade it to the latest 4.4.1 version?

Answer (score 3):

Try `rvm install 1.9.2 --with-gcc=clang` as explained in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8032980/429758

Comment: I ran the rvm install 1.9.2 --with-gcc=clang and it told me to reinstall     rvm reinstall 1.9.3 since I Already installed ruby-1.9.3-p194. I run it get an error towards the end on the reinstall that says `Error running '' under ,
please read /Users/connorphillips/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gemset.pristine.log`

Comment: The reason i'm trying to run 1.9.2 is because I feel like their might be a bug with 1.9.3. I get a mysql2 file not found error from running rake, and I thought running rvm 1.9.2 might fix that

Comment: The message asking you to reinstall 1.9.3 is likely to be an unrelated issue, since installations of ruby versions under rvm are independent of each other. Is there anything in the gemset.pristine.log? As for the mysql error, check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv/6100648#6100648 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437455/rake-dbmigrate-mysql It might be the same issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

```
'/usr/bin/gcc' is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

see:

```
, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

use:
$ rvm requirements

and install wthat you need. For Ruby, or JRuby ....

Answer (score 0):

installing this package (Mountain Lion) fit the bill for me.
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer