# rake db:create giving error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rake

When I run rake db:create I get following error

```
xyz-MacBook-Pro:ruby_project xyz$ rake db:create
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

I have mysql 5.1.66 installed in my system and my database.yml file structure is

```
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: ruby_test
pool: 5
username: root
password:
host: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Below are contents of mysql folder in my system

```
libdbug.a           libmysqlclient_r.a
libheap.a           libmysqlclient_r.dylib
libmygcc.a          libmysqlclient_r.la
libmyisam.a         libmysqld.a
libmyisammrg.a          libmystrings.a
libmysqlclient.16.dylib libmysys.a
libmysqlclient.a        libvio.a
libmysqlclient.dylib    libz.a
libmysqlclient.la       libz.la
libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib   plugin
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: The same issue has been satisfactorily answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557507/rails-mysql-on-osx-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib

Comment: It has libymysqlclient18.dylib which it was not able to find. In my case, I don't have libmysql18.dylib file.

Answer (score 4):

Install the gem for mysql2 using the command
    gem install mysql2
check the bundle to make sure it used mysql as default database.
And put the libmysql.dll file in your MySQL bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simple and best way is to create a soft link by command -

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/07/getting-error-library-not-loaded.html

Comment: I don't have libmysqlclient.18.dylib in mysql/lib folder. I have mentioned that ...

Answer (score 1):

You can install libmysqlclient. I guess you are using Ubuntu, then using following to install

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```