# Cannot execute "rails console" due to an error with readline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, homebrew, rbenv

I cannot execute `rails console` due to this error:

```
localhost:TwitterForZombies wiz$ rails c
/Users/wiz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': dlopen(/Users/wiz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.1/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/wiz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.1/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/wiz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.1/readline.bundle
    from /Users/wiz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/wiz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/wiz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/wiz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `require'
    from /Users/wiz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have installed readline via homebrew.
I'd like to keep using rbenv instead of rvm.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails console doesn't load due to libreadline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591527/rails-console-doesnt-load-due-to-libreadline)

Answer (score 277):

I had the same issue recently with homebrew and libreadline.7.x.dylib / libreadline.6.x.dylib

I solved it by running:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
```

source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26658

Comment: What a hack :) But it works just fine, for now :D Thanks!

Comment: Using symlinks to trick the system into using what is actually a different (major!) version number is generally a bad idea.  It would be good if someone more knowledgeable could explain why the above fix is safe.

Comment: You're a legend, thank you for this, @wiz should have marked you correct!

Comment: A cursory review of the changes between libreadline 6.3 and 7.0 don't show anything that appears to be a breaking change, expect in cases where software may have been relying on undocumented or buggy behavior. I'd be comfortable trying this solution in light of that.

Answer (score 58):

Homebrew is great, but once in a while it doesn't play nice with some of the other moving parts.

A `brew update && brew upgrade` brought in `libreadline.7.x.dylib` while automatically removing `libreadline.6.x.dylib`, which ruby was still relying on.

There may be more clever ways to fix the problem, but brute force worked for me:

```
$ rbenv uninstall 2.3.1
$ rbenv install 2.3.1
$ cd /path/to/my/app
$ bundle
```

The above assumes the presence of rbenv's `ruby-build` and, of course, `bundler`; replace `2.3.1` with whatever version of ruby you are using.

Please note that similar problems can occur with different homebrew-managed libraries ([see my own answer to this, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557507/rails-mysql-on-osx-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib/34737074#34737074))

Comment: Had the same just happen to me — I wonder if there isn't some way for Homebrew to notice that some libs are linked to older versions of some that Homebrew supplies?

Comment: This worked for me in El Capitan, with a `gem install bundler` after the rbenv install.

Comment: Will the error occur when I run `brew update && brew upgrade` again?

Comment: @FrankFang, it may or may not, and not just for this particular error. Every time a `brew upgrade` replaces ANY older library with a more recent version, there are SOME chances that other programs in your system will complain.

Answer (score 26):

I'm on OSX, ruby2.3.0, rails5. Adding `gem 'rb-readline'` to my `Gemfile` fixed this problem.

Comment: gem rb-readline worked for me. I added it to the :development, :test group - nice quick fix!

Answer (score 20):

As Sachin hinted, installing readline and then reinstalling ruby is the ideal approach - but the details are a bit different for rbenv. Given your file paths, I'm guessing you're on a Mac, so the following should help:

```
brew install readline ruby-build
env CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline` rbenv install 1.9.3-p286
```

This was taken from [the ruby-build Wiki](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki) and a quick google search.

Comment: don't forget to rehash after doing this

Comment: After re-installing an existing Ruby version with readline, running a command such as `bundle install` showed me lots of warnings like “Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built”. As suggested in the answers to [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147939/ruby-on-os-x-10-9-ignoring-gems-because-extensions-are-not-built), `gem pristine --all` fixed all of those errors at once.

Answer (score 20):

I got the same error with Ruby 2.1.0, and rails 4.0. After searching and trying a lot, finally it work well:) Here are what I did:

```
rvm cleanup all
rvm autolibs enable
rvm install 2.1.0
```

The other ways:

```
brew update
brew uninstall readline
brew install readline
```

The autolibs command will force RVM install all dependencies, so you don't need to worry about it.

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: you might not need to `cleanup rvm`.
just `reinstall` the ruby version.

Answer (score 8):

Using mac, `El Captain` version, it is possible to fix just by doing

```
rvm reinstall your_ruby_version
```

(like `rvm reinstall ruby-2.3.1`)

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: This was all I needed to do.

Comment: This will reinstall your current version: `rvm reinstall $(rvm current)`

Comment: This is the simplest solution, but it takes some time to reinstall. Still, best approach imho.

Answer (score 1):

taken from github user @enderahmetyurt (this is the only solution that worked for me). 
Solution: Add `gem 'rb-readline'` to your Gemfile in *development group* and *bundle install*. 
It's the easiest solution for silly "readline" errors.

Answer (score 0):

> try installing readline, and reinstall your ruby
>
> https://rvm.io/packages/readline/

Comment: thank you for answering, but is there any way to keep using rbenv instead of rvm?