# Rails MySQL Connection Problems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

I am having an issue connecting to the mysql database using rails. I'm a newbie to rails but I **have** tried the guide here:

[rails + MySQL on OSX: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557507/rails-mysql-on-osx-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib)

and this still does not work. I believe I have two installations of mysql installed and this is confusing rails.

I have MAMP installed with it's own mysql and I also have the rails mysql2 gem installed. When I follow the steps from the link provided above, I think this is using the MAMP mysql install instead of the mysql2 install that I have with rails gems so it isn't recognizing it.

Is there any way I can consolidate the two mysql's into one? Or is it easier to modify rails so it can see the mysql2 gem?

---

Here is my error:

```
~/Sites/RoR3-Essentials/simple_cms ->rails s
```

=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on `http://localhost:3000`

=> Call with -d to detach

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

Exiting

/Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in 
`connect': Unknown database 'simple_cms_development' (Mysql2::Error)

```
from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

from /Users/markmilly/Sites/RoR3-Essentials/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/markmilly/Sites/RoR3-Essentials/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `require'

from /Users/markmilly/Sites/RoR3-Essentials/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'

from /Users/markmilly/Sites/RoR3-Essentials/simple_cms/config.ru:in `new'

from /Users/markmilly/Sites/RoR3-Essentials/simple_cms/config.ru:in `<main>'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'

from /Users/markmilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'

from script/rails:6:in `require'

from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you do a rake db:create?

Comment: Please provide the contents of your database.yml..

Comment: This doesn't look like an "I don't know where MySQL is" connection error. It looks like a "You forgot to create your database" connection error.

Comment: the 'rake db:create' command worked! Thanks. So does that just create a database based on the name of the project?

Answer (score 0):

@markmilly Answer to your last comment:

'rake db:create' creates the db that you specified in your config/database.yml file.

It will create the db for the current RAILS_ENV you're on. If the environment is not specified it will default to the development and test db's.

I see this answer is a bit late, but it might help someone else.