# `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When I tried to run rails s on remote server I got this issue.

Mysql working fine with "rails db"

Answer (score 1):

Find your socket file using

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

And then add the socket file to your database.yml configuration

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: <socket location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the MySQL login/pass fine and is the mysql server running?