# rails server error in mac osx terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure why this did not work. Please see the following. I tried to comand rails s and the server did not start and gave me some sort of error that I am not understanding!

```
Muhammeds-MacBook-Pro:simple_cms muhammedz786$ rails s
    /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
      Referenced from: /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
      Reason: image not found - /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/rails_application/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    Muhammeds-MacBook-Pro:simple_cms muhammedz786$
```

Comment: Try that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10847618/2291093

Comment: MySQL server may not be started ```mysql.server start``` based on your other questions.