# rake db:migrate - rake aborted LoadError: dlopen && Error installing mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

So I'm trying to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

and got the following error

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/scott/Google Drive/playground/myApp/myApp/config/application.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/scott/Google Drive/playground/myApp/myApp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

I uninstalled mysql2 and then ran

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'
```

and hit the following error....

```
git:(master) ✗ gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
/Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180709-8149-znoxt9.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for rb_big_cmp()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Setting rpath to /usr/local/mysql/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
In file included from client.c:1:
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:41:
./result.h:24:3: error: unknown type name 'my_bool'
  my_bool *is_null;
  ^
./result.h:25:3: error: unknown type name 'my_bool'
  my_bool *error;
  ^
client.c:507:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool res = mysql_read_query_result(client);
  ^
client.c:509:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'res'
  return (void *)(res == 0 ? Qtrue : Qfalse);
                  ^
client.c:828:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool boolval;
  ^
client.c:859:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:860:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:863:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
    case MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH:
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/mysql/include/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
client.c:864:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:865:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:896:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
        wrapper->reconnect_enabled = boolval;
                                     ^
client.c:1285:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
  return _mysql_client_options(self, MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH, value);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/mysql/include/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
12 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.4.0-static/mysql2-0.4.5/gem_make.out
```

I have tried adding the following to my .bash_profile like other suggestions

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

But no luck.  I also have Mysql 8.0.11 running in the background..

Any ideas?

Comment: have you installed all the mysql dev libraries ?

Comment: @Subash I've installed Mysql?  How do I check if the libraries are installed?

Comment: how did you install mysql ?

Comment: @Subash - Using a dmg file from mysql.com - Community server.  I think my solution might be in the lower answers of here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557507/rails-mysql-on-osx-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib - but not sure.

Comment: try it and see what happens ?