# Rails server won't start on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion

Ok, I just created a new project.  I did the bundle install.  Rails server will not start.  It gives me all this:

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in`'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`block in require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/foximusprime/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in`'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`block in '
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in`'

I have no idea what's going on.  Just an hour ago the server was working.  Close everything out and come home from work and now it gives me all this junk.  I don't have a clue what to do.

Comment: This question is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv

Comment: omg thank you so much.  I've looked everywhere on here and tried all kinds of things and nothing worked but now it does.  Now I can get back to learning to use ruby and rails.  Thank you so much!