# ln: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: File exists

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, rake, osx-mountain-lion

```
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/ava/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ava/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/ava/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle`
```

Ran the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6100648/602524) to resolve:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib \
             /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
ln: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: File exists
```

My setup:

- OSX 10.8.4
- MySQL 5.1.71
- libmysqlclient.16.dylib

  ```
  $ locate libmysqlclient.16.dylib
  /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql51/5.1.71/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
  ```
- libmysqlclient.18.dylib

  ```
  $ locate libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  ```

In `.bash_profile`, I have

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

How to get this rake running? Am I supposed to have `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` under `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql51/5.1.71/lib/mysql` too? If yes, how do I create it?

Comment: Maybe describe how you got here?  Everything about what you're doing screams "NO!" so it's hard to help you.

Comment: `brew install --use-llvm mysql51` and then `mysql.server start`

Comment: After the above two commands, ran rake and got this error. Somewhere I have messed up the mysql installation but not able to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, if I am mistaken; there is no Mac to check in details.

The error message clearly states, that the library `mysql` wants is:

```
/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

while the library you have is:

```
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

That definitely means, that your `mysql` installation is somehow broken, but for the quick patch I would recommend soft linking:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

You have likely misplaced arguments within your first solution try.

Comment: Can you please explain what it is doing? Why doesnt `locate libmysqlclient.18.dylib` show it under `/usr/local/lib/`?

Comment: It’s doing exactly what you’ve tried according to the solution, except of one humdrum thing: it states args in the _right_ order. `locate libmysqlclient.18.dylib` shows it where it is. And in your case it is in `/usr/lib` rathen than the expected `/usr/local/lib`. Sorry for libmysqlclient, sorry for Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Instruct Mac OS X to find it as follows, if you are using Bash:

In your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<location of mysqlclient.18.dylib>:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Restart terminal.

For example, I have the following:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/m*
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   27 May  5 14:28 /usr/local/mysql -> mysql-5.6.13-osx10.7-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102 May  5 13:13 /usr/local/mysql-5.5.29-osx10.6-x86
drwxr-xr-x  17 root  wheel  578 May  5 13:13 /usr/local/mysql-5.6.13-osx10.7-x86_64

$ head ~/.bash_profile
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```