# El Capitan upgrade: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, osx-elcapitan, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Error:

```
/Users/askar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': dlopen(/Users/askar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/askar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/askar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

In Gemfile: `gem 'mysql2'`

**$ ls -al /usr/local/lib/libmysql***

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 askar  admin  49 Nov 13 10:48 /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 askar  admin  42 Nov 13 10:48 /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.a -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib/libmysqlclient.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 askar  admin  46 Nov 13 10:48 /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 askar  admin  37 Nov 13 10:48 /usr/local/lib/libmysqld.a -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib/libmysqld.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 askar  admin  44 Nov 13 10:48 /usr/local/lib/libmysqlservices.a -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib/libmysqlservices.a
```

**$ ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib/**

```
total 84392
drwxr-xr-x   9 askar  admin       306 Nov 12 22:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 askar  admin       476 Nov 13 10:48 ..
-r--r--r--   1 askar  admin   3780168 Nov 13 10:48 libmysqlclient.20.dylib
-r--r--r--   1 askar  admin   4280752 Nov 12 22:16 libmysqlclient.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 askar  admin        23 Nov 12 22:16 libmysqlclient.dylib -> libmysqlclient.20.dylib
-r--r--r--   1 askar  admin  35126528 Nov 12 22:16 libmysqld.a
-r--r--r--   1 askar  admin      9048 Nov 12 22:16 libmysqlservices.a
drwxr-xr-x   3 askar  admin       102 Nov 13 10:48 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x  43 askar  admin      1462 Nov 12 22:17 plugin
drwxr-xr-x  43 askar  admin      1462 Nov 12 22:17 plugin
```

As you see I'm having `libmysqlclient.20.dylib`, it's `20` not `18`, otherwise I'd follow the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465283/1745902).

I've recently upgraded to El Capitan but not sure it that's the cause.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Rashmirathi for the hint to re-install the gem.

Just wanted to note, I needed also to specify in Gemfile as:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

Otherwise I had error:

> Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

But finally I got error:

> Mysql2::Error
>       Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.

Which is solved by setting up a password again:

```
SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('your_password');
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue immediately after upgrading to El Captain. Not sure why apple hasnt fixed the issue yet. Even after upgrading mysql and MySQL-python via pip the issue persists.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I was getting the same issue earlier on, I fixed it by reinstalling the gem `mysql2`.

Comment: I did some update on my post you might be interested in... ;)

Comment: For future reference, I got to this thread due to similar problems in Python and pip, and this solution also worked (pip uninstall MySQL-python && pip install MySQL-python).

Comment: If there is only one version of the mysql installed, then re installing is only the solution.

Answer (score 42):

this will solve your problem:

```
gem pristine mysql2
```

> solution by [Cesar Sulbarán](http://mailto:cesar@castamic.com)

Answer (score 23):

For those on OS X El Capitain or more, this fix my problem:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

For more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/32875545/1066915

Comment: for me this is a more generic solution:
  ln -nfs /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Answer (score 5):

I had an analogous problem in python: `libmysqlclient.20.dylib` instead of `18` on El Capitan. `pip install --upgrade mysql` fixed it, but only works in python2.

Comment: Relevant lib is installed as `pip install MySQL-python`. However `--upgrade` didn't work for me as I had latest version of the lib which has been broken for some reason. Combination uninstall + install worked for me.

Comment: @arsenyinfo this worked for me. I got the errors from updating/upgrading brew.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Homebrew so I've fixed this problem by clearing up everything step by step:

1. Comment out the mysql2 gem in in the Rails app Gemfile

   "# gem 'mysql2'"
2. Remove mysql2 gem from bundle

   bundle install
3. Uninstall the mysql2 gem (all versions)

   gem uninstall mysql2
4. Update Homebrew

   brew update
5. Uninstall all versions of mysql

   brew uninstall --force mysql
6. Reinstall mysql

   brew install mysql
7. Uncomment mysql2 gem in Gemfile

   gem mysql2
8. Add mysql2 to bundle

   bundle install

This approach might be a bit overkill but feels clean to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to chime in here- I just had the same problem with the libmysqlclient.18.dylib 18-20 difference. reinstalling the `mysql` gem (a dependency of the `activerecord-mysql-adapter`) made the difference. reinstalling `mysql2` did nothing.

editing to clarify: my error message traced back to my mysql gem, but i found this thread via searching so i'm including it here:

```
Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (dlopen(/Users/eriks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle, 9): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib 
Referenced from: /Users/eriks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/eriks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle) (LoadError)
```