# Unable to start server in rails with mysql db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, webrick

I get the following msg when using rails s or rail server in a terminal window. I am in the app root directory. Any ideas?

```
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require':     dlopen(/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle,     9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-    0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/paul/Documents/Ruby/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post your gem list?

Comment: Have fixed this now, by adding:    'sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have fixed this now, by adding:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```