# Mysql2 gem + Mavericks + Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having hell with this after I upgraded a machine to Mavericks and I am just not able to get rails running again. I have tried reinstalling mysql via brew, I have reinstalled MAMP, I have reinstalled the mysql2 gem. All in vain. I also tried creating soft links as mentioned in 
[Unable to start server in rails with mysql db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757276/unable-to-start-server-in-rails-with-mysql-db)
This is my error:

```
/Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.13/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.13/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/Desktop/arjun/work/colloquy_new/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/babblerstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I looked at the answer here [Unable to start server in rails with mysql db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757276/unable-to-start-server-in-rails-with-mysql-db) and when I ran the command, nothing changed, now it tells me that the file already exists.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
ln: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: File exists
```

I am so frustrated with this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled EVERYTHING. Node, rvm, ruby, all gems. And it worked.

Comment: Yeah. I normally do. It's a friends project I was helping out on.