# Rails Server Error - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rbenv, rbenv-gemset

I am trying to come back to create another application on Rail4 and When I try to start the application this is what happened:

```
    prompt$ rails server
    /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': dlopen(/Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
    Referenced from: /Users/edwincaro/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
   Reason: image not found - /Users/edwincaro/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
   from /Users/ec/Sites/ticketsys/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
   from /Users/ec/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
   from bin/rails:4:in `require'
   from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
   prompt$
```

I read all the 'Rails Server Error' posted previously here and tried most of the solution offered here but none of them worked for me.

I am thinking that maybe is the file dlopen what I am missing.

I will appreciate any help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib error when trying to run 'rails server' on OS X 10.6 with mysql2 gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv)

Comment: yeah, your mysql  database is not properly installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinstall your `mysql` library. Then:

`gem uninstall mysql2`

`bundle install`

To rebuild the gem against the new mysql library

Comment: I reinstalled mysql2 many times and the problem happened over and over. I just switched to another Database.